# Select everything right of `~`

Tags: r

I have written a function in which the user specifies a linear model (e.g., `y~x+tx+x*tx`). After the user specifies this model, I want to use their input to create a new formula with a different `y`.

I am thinking I just need to select `~x+tx+x*tx` portion of the formula and then paste that with a new `y` variable. How can I do this? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps most obvious (which didn't occur to me until just now...how sad)

```
form <- y~x+tx+x*tx
update(form, new_y ~ .)
```

There are a few ways to approach this, but this might be my preferred (at least for now).

```
form <- y~x+tx+x*tx
rhs <- sub(".+~", "", deparse(form))
as.formula(paste0("new_y ~", rhs))
```

You can also get the right hand side with

```
tail(as.character(form), 1)
```

But that assume that there is a right hand side of the formula.